# Please explain what really happens in description

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading the **Python crash course** to start learning python and when there came a part

```
>>> favorite_language = 'python '
>>> favorite_language
'python '
>>> favorite_language.rstrip()
'python'
>>> favorite_language
'python '
```

The author then mentioned that the use of method `rstrip()` is temporary and to make it permanent we have to do following

```
>>> favorite_language = 'python '
>>> favorite_language = favorite_language.rstrip()
>>> favorite_language
'python
```

I am confused in second step here

```
 >>> favorite_language = favorite_language.rstrip()
```

if we see from basics when python is interpreting this and reaches second step it thinks that it has to store a new value for favorite_language and it formats the variable and starts storing new value but after = a method is called on the same variable to store value for the same variable.

Shouldn't this cause error?

Comment: In an assignment operation `=`,  the RHS i.e. `fav_lang.rstrip()` is evaluated first. `rstrip()` returns a new string object. Which is then assigned to the `fav_lang` variable.

Comment: @rdas you meant RHS

Comment: @rdas I hope that you meant RHS. Also is this defined by the founder of python or there is some logic behind it?.
I appologize if this was a noob question

Comment: Yes, edited to RHS.  This is more or less how assignment works in every programming language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `favorite_language = favorite_language.rstrip()` reassigns the `favorite_language` with new value, which is the value returned from the `favorite_language.rstrip()`.

The `favorite_language.rstrip()` itself does not change the original string (`str()` in Python is immutable in any case) just by calling the method. To have the `favorite_language` modified we have to explicitly say:

*"Hey, `favorite_language`, here's new value for you"*.

Which is: `favorite_language = new_value`

But in this case the new value is the value that the `favorite_language.rstrip()` returns.

All the expressions on the right side of the `=` are **evaluated before any assignment happens**. Also, since `str()` in Python is immutable, calling `favorite_language.rstrip()` is not modifying anything, it **produces new value**, which then can be stored in the `favorite_language`. So, the production of the new value happens before any reassignment.

For more on the evaluation order (*and many more*), check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#evaluation-order).

Comment: Hi pal thanks for the answer but I think you misunderstood my question.

Comment: I wanted to ask like if we are assigning favorite_language a new value which is going to be served by a operation performed on same variable. SO wouldn't this affect the value stored?

Comment: @PranavAggarwal you want to know why is it ok to assign a new value while calling a method on the same variable?

Comment: No, this explains exactly what you asked, though in perhaps _too_ newbie-friendly terms. The long and the short of it is that the expression to the right is evaluated first.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal check the edit on the answer.

Comment: @rawrex Thank you. Last question- is RHS evaluated first a rule used in every language? and what is the reason behind it? and how to know these basic rules?. These are not mentioned in python crash course.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal that's why it is only a "crash course". I'll edit in a link for this in the documentation in a minute.

Comment: Thanks a lot @rawrex. Can you please suggest me if I am going on  a right path or not. I fthe book python crash course suited for me if i follow this approach.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal it depends. I would prefer to get into a well received book first *(there many of these, just check into a search engine)* and ignore "crash courses" at all. Dig into problems and exercises and parallel all this with looking into the documentation.

Comment: @rawrex after searching on Google almost all the websites recommend Python crash course.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal probably advertising. There are good books ;)

Answer (score 0):

In basically every imperative language (and many others!), assignments look something like

```
lvalue ← expression
```

where the semantics are "evaluate *expression,* and assign the result to *lvalue".*

There are many situations where it would be very cumbersome indeed if you could not use *lvalue* itself in *expression,* and have it refer to the *previous* value of *lvalue*. There are many algorithms where you need to add or subtract one from an index variable, or add a new term to an accumulator. Conversely, there are *no* situations where it's a useful feature to not be able to do so. But some primitive languages really did require you to use a temporary variable in these scenarios.

The fact that the assignment operator in Python (and C, and a lot of other languages) looks identical to the mathematical symbol for equality is confusing to some beginners; this is why some languages use a left arrow instead, or a stylized ASCII approximation like `:=` (in Pascal; and now also with slightly different semantics in Python) or `:-` (in e.g. Prolog).

Comment: There are probably some esoteric languages where using *lvalue* in *expression* really does refer to its future value, for humorous and/or frustrating reasons. Compare to [the `COMEFROM` jump statement in INTERCAL.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/COMEFROM)